# Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP destroys the destination activity. How to avoid?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle, appcompatactivity

I'm trying to return back to an activity which is in the activity stack, deleting all the activitys between the current one and the destination activity.

I Readed that this is the way to achieve it:

```
Intent i = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Supposedly it will finish all the activities between the current and the destination, **but also is destroying the destination activity.**

This is not the behaviour I was looking for. I need to avoid the destruction of the destination activity. It should resume itself instead of being destroyed and recreated.

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

When you use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, Android removes all activities on top of the target `Activity` including the existing instance of the target `Activity` and then creates a new instance of the target `Activity`. If you want to use the existing instance of the target `Activity`, you need to also specify `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`.